# Cómo solucionar el error 403 al subir mi sitio a la web, en hostinger

Tags: php, html, web

tengan ustedes muy buenas tardes, lo que pasa es que estoy terminando un proyecto, el cual funciona bien en el localhost así que debo subirlo a la web, para ello compré un alojamiento y un dominion en hostinger, el cuál ya tenia una página web de otro proyecto con WordPress, pero ahora netamente subí mis archivos propios, o sea los .php, etc.. nada de wordpress, por lo que borré todo, al momento de cargar mi web me aparece el error 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied!, ya cargué todos mis archivos y también cambié mis rutas en providers y AppResources, lo que no entiendo es porqué me aparece eso, además también he otorgado los permisos necesarios, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Qué es el error 403 Prohibido? 403 Prohibido – No tiene permiso para
> acceder a / en este servidor es un código de estado HTTP que se
> produce cuando el servidor web entiende la solicitud pero no puede
> proporcionarte acceso.

Navega a "hosting" del dominio seleccionado, ahí selecciona "Administrodor de archivos" se te abrirá la nueva ventana de tu navegador y verás la carpeta "public_html"

Copia tus archivos dentro de esta carpeta

*recordatorios:* No copies la carpeta en la que tienes tus archivos
la estructura debe ser más o menos así, dependiendo de tu proyecto

```
public_html
  |
  |assets/
     |_css/
       |_main.css
     |_javascript/
       |_app.js
  |_index.php
```

asegurate de no dejar archivos como **.htaccess** dentro de la carpeta "public_html"

---

Es posible que hayas apuntado a la dirección IP incorrecta, asegúrate de revisar si el registro A está configurado al mismo desde tu plan de hosting.

Para obtener información adicional sobre la reparación de errores 403 hostinger tiene tutorial¿Qué es el error 403 prohibido (Forbidden 403 error) y cómo solucionarlo?

Para obtener información detallada sobre cualquier error 403 encontrado en tu sitio web, puedes consultar la sección **Registros de acceso** en **hPanel**, así con más información se puede aconsejar mejor

Comment: Hola cree que me pueda asesorar con ello? quisiera hacer la subida, estoy desesperado, le pagaría por ello

Comment: ahora me aparece el error 500, no sé qué hacer

Comment: ya borré el HTACCES para poder descartar el problema, pero sigue apareciendo

Comment: ¿Tenías WordPress instalado antes no? Sinceramente, creo que es problema del WordPress, revisa que no te haya quedado ningún archivo de WordPress, ni carpetas, también asegúrate de no estar usando la misma base de datos. También asegúrate que tu proyecto tiene archivo *index.php* o *index.html*

si ves que nada de esto te ayuda, Hostinger tiene muy buena atención al cliente ;)